# Peak/Trough detection with Specific strength

Tags: matlab

Is there anyway that I can detect a peak or trough with a specific strength.

What I mean is if `A` is a vector than a value is peak if and only if its value is higher than the previous `N` elements and higher then the the next `M` elements.

Obviously this can be done with loops, but is there anything simple which can do this through vector operations.

Answer (score 0):

I think that

```
[...] = findpeaks(data,'Name',value)
```

may help you.

Comment: Unfortunately findpeaks has no concept of look back or look forward strength.